# manually continuing loops

Tags: c

I have a file where each line consists of some words and a number. I'd like to read the file, one line at a time, displaying just the words. Then the program should wait for a key press, and display the number on a certain key, and go on to the next line without displaying the number in the default case. My problem is, the only solution I came up with displays the *next* line with a number, not the current one. Here's the faulty code;

```
  FILE *file = fopen("randwords", "r");
  if(file)
  {
    char line[64];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file))
    {
      ch = getch();
      clear();
      if(ch == 'q') break;
      if(ch == 'z') s = 1;
      move(LINES/2, (COLS - 20)/2);
      for(i=0; i < strlen(line); i++)
      {
        if(!s && line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9') break;
        addch(line[i]);
      }
      s = 0;
    }
    fclose(file);
    system("rm randwords");
  }
```

Comment: is the number at the end of the line (i.e. no words after the number)?

Comment: What's missing in your question: the format of lines, with samples, how are you outputting the data (what's move()? addch()?)

Comment: these are curses functions, to move cursor and display a character on screen; irrelevant to question

Answer (score 2):

use ftell() and fseek() to allow you to reread a line. You will need a variable to hold the previous file position.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're doing:

```
read line
wait for key
print *full* line if key was 'z'
    or print words only otherwise
```

Note that you are waiting for key with no line displaying on the first time through the loop, or, as you say, with the line from the last pass through the loop.

This is what you should be doing:

```
read line
print words only
wait for key
if key was 'z'
    print rest of line
```